# Transforming java source code to move annotations from getters to properties

Tags: java, inria-spoon, program-transformation

I have about 300 JPA entities where the getters are annotated with persistence annotations. I would like to find a way to move all such annotations to the properties instead and remove all getters and setters. I did this manually for about 100 of these classes but it's very time consuming and mind numbing work.

I'm looking at source code transformation tools like [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr) but still not sure it can do what I need it to do.

More specifically, how can I transform this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "crm_ticket")
public class CrmTicket implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -902718555957517699L;

    private CrmAccount crmAccount;
    private ItsType subType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account")
    public CrmAccount getCrmAccount() {
        return crmAccount;
    }

    public void setCrmAccount(CrmAccount crmAccount) {
        this.crmAccount = crmAccount;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_type")
    public ItsType getSubType() {
        return subType;
    }

    public void setSubType(ItsType type) {
        this.subType = type;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "crm_ticket")
@Data
public class CrmTicket implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -902718555957517699L;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account")
    private CrmAccount crmAccount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_type")
    private ItsType subType;
}
```

Comment: I wonder how I can limit the scope of this question? It's very specific as it stands! How do you transform a class so that annotations from getters are put on the properties instead? Isn't this problem specific enough?

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I suspect it might get closed again because it sounds like you are looking for an off-site resource / tool. Maybe described what you tried you so far. Personally I would probably use some kind of awk script, but that's just me. Would definitely be curious what solution you finally settle on.

Comment: Thanks @SiKing. I tried initially with awk/sed but this kind of transformation requires the tool to have some knowledge of java syntax. I will post here my solution using Spoon which is a very cool source transformation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/). It wasn't that painful. I configured their maven plugin to run my processor and it transformed the code of my Entity classes. I then copied the generated code back to my project and removed the plugin configuration.

Here's my processor code:

```
public class JpaAnnotationMover extends AbstractProcessor<CtMethod> {

    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("return.*this\\.(.*?)$");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("return(.*?)$");

    @Override
    public boolean isToBeProcessed(CtMethod method) {
        return isInEntity(method) && isAGetter(method) && hasOneStatement(method) && !isTransient(method);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(CtMethod ctMethod) {
CtType parentClass = ctMethod.getParent(CtType.class);
        String fieldName = getFieldName(ctMethod);

        if (fieldName == null) {
            log.warn(String.format("expected field name for %s not found.", ctMethod.getSimpleName()));
            return;
        }

        CtField field = parentClass.getField(fieldName);
        if (field == null) {
            log.warn(String.format("Expected field %s not found.", fieldName));
            return;
        }

        for (CtAnnotation<? extends Annotation> annotation : ctMethod.getAnnotations()) {
            field.addAnnotation(annotation);
        }

        parentClass.removeMethod(ctMethod);
        log.info(String.format("Processed method %s:%s", parentClass.getSimpleName(), ctMethod.getSimpleName()));

        // find corresponding setter
        String setterName = "set" + WordUtils.capitalize(fieldName);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") CtMethod setter = parentClass
                .getMethod(getFactory().Type().createReference("void"), setterName, ctMethod.getType());

        if (setter == null) {
            log.warn(String.format("Unable to find setter for %s", fieldName));
            return;
        }

        parentClass.removeMethod(setter);

        if (!parentClass.hasAnnotation(Data.class)) {
            parentClass.addAnnotation(getFactory().createAnnotation(getFactory().Type().createReference(Data.class)));
        }
}

private Boolean isInEntity(CtMethod method) {
        CtType parentClass = method.getParent(CtType.class);
        return parentClass.hasAnnotation(Entity.class);
    }

    private Boolean isAGetter(CtMethod method) {
        return method.getSimpleName().contains("get");
    }

    private Boolean hasOneStatement(CtMethod method) {
        return method.getBody().getStatements().size() == 1;
    }

    private Boolean isTransient(CtMethod method) {
        return method.hasAnnotation(Transient.class);
    }

    private String getFieldName(CtMethod method) {
        String statement = method.getBody().getLastStatement().toString();
        Matcher m = p1.matcher(statement);
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(statement);
        return m.matches() ? m.group(1).trim() : m2.matches() ? m2.group(1).trim() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spoon would work well for this, you would use aField.[addAnnotation](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/blob/9db1d7754f14743f79632d8073e45c109d7aed22/src/main/java/spoon/support/reflect/declaration/CtElementImpl.java#L224) and  aSetter.[delete](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/blob/151176f4fae4d472c5bad16fc07c384ec85ca207/src/main/java/spoon/reflect/declaration/CtElement.java#L291).